# How do I go About Creating Exam Prep with Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to begin a mobile app project for my college, i want to make use of flutter but am a beginner. The app is going to base on past questions of various departments of my college.

The questions will popping randomly with timer. How do i go about this?

I also need suggestion whether to make the app Online or Offline. 
Making it Online, am thinking of getting the random questions from a rest API that outputs results in JSON but some of the users of the app might not be able to afford buying internet Data. 
Making it Offline, i need how to go about this with Dart/Flutter. and also i'd like the size of the app not to be much as having questions stored in the app (Offline) might increase the size of the app.

I need suggestions on how to achieve my aims with Dart/Flutter please.

Comment: That's too broad. Stackoverflow should be used to ask questions that can have a unique working answer.

Comment: You might get better feedback in https://gitter.im/flutter/flutter (or other Flutter related channels). StackOverflow is for concrete programming problems.